# Whats is the right way to get elapsed time and reset it

Tags: java, android

In my android program I am using two Calendar instances to get the elapsed time in my program, first I set a level starting time as follows:

```
level_Start_TimeCal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

and in my thread I am calculating elapsed time as follows:

```
level_current_TimeCal = Calendar.getInstance();
gameTime = level_current_TimeCal.getTimeInMillis()- level_Start_TimeCal.getTimeInMillis();                      
dsecs = (gameTime / 1000)%60;
dminutes = (gameTime / (60 * 1000))%60;
dhours = (gameTime / (60 * 60 * 1000))%60;
```

Recently I came to read the following:

> Calendar's getInstance method returns a Calendar object whose calendar
>   fields have been initialized with the current date and time

I want to know if I am in right path?
Am I creating an object each time the thread running?
If yes is there any alternative to avoid creating unwanted objects and calculating elapsed time?
Final question: at some point I want to reset the time in my restart method I reset it by just calling getInstance in my reset method as follows:

```
public void restart() {
 level_Start_TimeCal = Calendar.getInstance();
}
```

Is this the correct way to reset the Calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to calculate elapsed time is to use [`System.nanotime()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29).

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
//do something
long end = System.nanoTime();

//to get the elapsed time, you can use the TimeUnit utility methods:
long elapsedInNanos = end - start;
long elapsedInSeconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(elapsedInNanos, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

Note that it is not a useful method to access absolute time.